# Sorting columns in a multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I want to sort a multidimensional array using the first row,
I want that the second and the third row get the same sort order of the first row

Here is an example of array :

```
var arr = 
[
[1,3,5,6,0,2],
[1,2,7,4,0,6],
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
]
```

the result that I want =

```
[
[0,1,2,3,5,6],
[0,1,6,2,7,4],
[5,1,6,2,3,4]
]
```

I tried the following function but it doesnt work as I want

```
arr = arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a[0] > b[0];
});
```

What's wrong with my function ?
Thank you

Comment: Could you post the desired result?

Comment: not clear what description of column sort means

Comment: Another thing is that [`.sort` should return a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), not a bool.

Comment: So why don't you create an array with **[arr[0],arr[0],arr[0]]** will have the same result.

Comment: Can you describe how second and third arrays should be sorted ? Why should `5` be at index `0` of third array ?

Comment: are duplicates possible within each row?

Comment: I believe OP is saying that if item in index N of the first array is moved to index M then whatever element is in arrays 2 and 3 at index N should be moved to index M.

Comment: No duplication for the first row ... and the second and thirds rows use the same index of sorting of the first row

Comment: Is anybody else confused on the OP's description? I don't get how you concluded the 2nd and 3rd row based on your direction.

Comment: Yes @MattLo: me, my self and I.

Comment: The first row is sorted from lowes to highest value ... the index of this sort = 4,0,5,1,2,3 (in my example) .. I should sort the 2d and the third rows using the same index of sorting (4,0,5,1,2,3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand what you're looking for:

```js
a = [
[1,3,5,6,0,2],
[1,2,7,4,0,6],
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
]

transpose = m => m[0].map((_, c) => m.map(r => r[c]));

z = transpose(transpose(a).sort((x, y) => x[0] - y[0]))

z.map(r => 
    document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(r) + '</pre>'));
```

In ES5

```
transpose = function(m) {
    return m[0].map(function (_, c) {
        return m.map(function (r) {
            return r[c]
        })
    })
};

z = transpose(transpose(a).sort(function (x, y) { return x[0] - y[0] }));
```

UPD: the transpose trick is kinda "smart", but hardly efficient, if your matrices are big, here's a faster way:

```js
a = [
[1,3,5,6,0,2],
[1,2,7,4,0,6],
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
]

t = a[0].map((e, i) => [e, i]).sort((x, y) => x[0] - y[0]);
z = a.map(r => t.map(x => r[x[1]]));

z.map(r => 
    document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(r) + '</pre>'));
```

Basically, sort the first row and remember indexes, then for each row, pick values by an index.

Comment: Could you translate that into English, please?

Comment: @MikeC: the OP wants to sort columns in a matrix, so we transpose it, sort rows and then transpose again.

Comment: @georg I guess I just need to do my reading on transposing. If I read the code enough it'll come together, I just didn't know if there was a way of explaining this to a layman.

Comment: @MikeC transposing just flips the matrix (rows become columns columns become rows)

Comment: @thedarklord47 Ooooooh! That makes sense. You're right, that is dirty.

Comment: Hi @georg, your function is working if I run it in the console... however When I put it in a function in my program it makes error ... (here is a screenshot : http://snag.gy/sioEE.jpg)  any idea ?

Comment: probably lack of arrow function support

Comment: @taboubim: your platform probably doesn't support fat arrow functions. Replace them with normal `function`s.

Comment: @taboubim: added an ES5 version.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more verbose than previous answer in ES5

```js
var arr = [
   [1, 3, 5, 6, 0, 2],
   [1, 2, 7, 4, 0, 6],
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 ]
 var sortIndices = arr[0].slice().sort(function(a, b) {
   return a - b;
 }).map(function(el) {
   return arr[0].indexOf(el)
 });

 arr = arr.reduce(function(a, c) {
   var sorted = sortIndices.map(function(i) {
     return c[i];
   });
   a.push(sorted);
   return a;
 }, []);

 document.getElementById('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr)
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @charlietfl